# What's a good low-maintenance poolside lawn choice in Zone 8?

Tags: lawn

I need a lawn solution for around our backyard pool.  The previous owners had the area covered in flagstone, but I need more green in my life!

Info about the area:

- We're in North Dallas, Zone 8.
- Lots of dry hot summers; but there will be sprinklers.
- Something that doesn't need a lot of mowing would be nice.
- Since it will be around a pool, it'll need to stand up to heavy traffic.

Answer (score 2):

This is a toughie question.  Lawn would be the only answer for heavy traffic and green.  Oh, shoot, there IS astroturf...what did you not like about the flagstone?  Isn't Texas kinda tough on using too much water for your landscape?  Flagstone, gravel would have to have about 10'width of concrete by the pool so that gravel/sand wouldn't be tracked into the pool. There are a lot of plants called 'stepables' but can not take heavy traffic.  Again, there is Astroturf...grins!  Please send pictures of your pool and surrounding landscape!!